# Read files with Dropbox core API - do I need to use OAuth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth-2.0, dropbox

I am terrible at figuring out REST documentation.

Stuck already with trying to get a simple folder view going after reading the documentation at Dropbox.

If the folder is publicly shared, why would I need to use any authentication to allow reading of file contents?

I'm just trying to make a simple image gallery from a folder. If I'm using jQuery, shouldn't I be able to do a simple get("...Dropbox/...access token .../folder name") and get a response like they say in the docs?

Comment: I've used DropBox to store static `.json` before and never needed to authorize the `GET` if it was in a public folder.  Make sure your URL is correct :)

Comment: Some more specifics here would be helpful. If you do have a public link, you don't need to use the API. Post a sample link in that case? If you don't have a public link, you do need to use the API to access file content, and the API calls will need some authentication, in the form of an access token. For reference, the Dropbox API supports both OAuth 1 and OAuth 2. Maybe post some code in that case?